# Content Security Policy does not work in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-core, internet-explorer-11, content-security-policy, coreclr

In my asp.net core application for each response i'm adding content security policy header. I understand that for IE, the header name is `X-Content-Security-Policy` and for other browsers like chrome its `Content-Security-Policy`

The header value looks something like below where `nonce` is different for each response.

```
default-src 'none';   
script-src 'self' 'nonce-somerandomvalue-differnt-foreach-reasone' 'unsafe-eval';  
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';   
img-src 'self' data:;   
font-src 'self';    
object-src 'self';   
connect-src 'self';   
report-uri /csp/report;
```

The application is using inline javascript on few pages. So to fix inline-script violation i am adding same `nonce` value in script tag.
`<script type="text/javascript" nonce="somerandomvalue-differnt-foreach-reasone">`
Important thing here is the nonce value needs to match with the nonce value in header. [some details here](http://www.cspplayground.com/compliant_examples)

I implemented middleware & tag-helper which adds nonce into header & script tag respectively. And i made sure that both `nonce` values does match when page renders.

Then just for testing purpose on a page i added script **without nonce**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        alert('i am hacker');
    })
</script>
```

Google chrome detects this violation and blocks the above script as expected. However in IE 11 above script gets executed without any violation. Again, I made sure the header in IE is `X-Content-Security-Policy`

Why IE 11 is not blocking script?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

IE 11 doesn’t support use of the `nonce` attribute and `nonce-` source value at all.

[The only CSP directive IE11 supports is the `sandbox` directive](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/07/14/defense-in-depth-locking-down-mash-ups-with-html5-sandbox/). It ignores all other CSP directives.

So you could just completely drop the `'nonce-somerandomvalue-differnt-foreach-reasone'` part from your `X-Content-Security-Policy` header and IE11 will still allow inline scripts.

IE11 will allow inline scripts no matter what you do, unless you have your server send the response with a `X-Content-Security-Policy: sandbox` header, in which case it will disallow *all* scripts. And the only way to relax that is to send `X-Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-scripts`, but that will allow all scripts, including inline scripts.

So I think that with IE11 there’s no way to tell it to disallow just inline scripts. You can only tell IE11 to either allow all scripts, or to allow none.

---

Also note: IE11 was released in 2013, long before the `nonce` attribute was specified anywhere. I think the first CSP draft spec that the `nonce` attribute was specified in was some time in 2014.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy has details on browser support for [CSP1 directives](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-CSP-20121115/):

> Partial support in Internet Explorer 10-11 refers to the browser only supporting the 'sandbox' directive by using the `X-Content-Security-Policy` header.

The `nonce` attribute is [a CSP2 feature](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/). See http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy2

[Support for `nonce` and other CSP2 features was added in Edge 15](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/01/10/edge-csp-2/). So Edge 14 and earlier have no support for `nonce` or other new-in-CSP2 features. But Edge12+ has full support for [all of CSP1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-CSP-20121115/).