# Am I using X-Content-Security-Policy correctly?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, content-security-policy

I am trying to use my Content-Security-Policy for Internet Explorer

Here's the Content-Security-Policy I have:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">`

This is what I've added for X-Content-Security-Policy

`<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">`

I see loads of inline styles warnings (and others) when I open my document using MS Edge, Firefox, or Chrome. But I don't see anything in IE. And I can still run scripts on the page in IE, which I can't do (and want to prevent) on the other browsers I mentioned.

So this makes me wonder: Am I using the X-Content-Security-Policy meta tag correctly? If not, how do I fix my tag? And also, where can I find documentation for X-Content-Security-Policy? I've searched on X-Content-Security-Policy... I haven't been able to find anything. The things that come up are for Content-Security-Policy

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>

<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'"><meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">

<script src="./jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
alert('boo');
</script>
</head>
<body>
Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSP is only partial supported in IE10-11. You can see in the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#Browser_compatibility), it doesn't support `<meta>` element in IE. And [partial support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP#Browser_compatibility) means it only supports the 'sandbox' directive by using the X-Content-Security-Policy header. For more details, you can also check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42937146/content-security-policy-does-not-work-in-internet-explorer-11).

Comment: Thank you your answer and the link are very informative